# Uninstalling heroku plugin in Windows

Tags: heroku

I attempted installing the heroku-accounts plugin on my windows machines, but got the following error when first trying to add an account:

*!    Resource not found*

Now for all commands, I'm getting the error:

*No such account:*

Even when I try to uninstall the plugin I get this error, so am completely dead in the water.

Any ideas?